# How to create and serialize an unmanaged model Django

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I've currently got existing tables in my database that were created with models as per the usual way (using `makemigrations` and `migrate`).

Now, I am looking to combine certain data from these existing tables, without having to create a new table in my database. Then, I would like to serialise that data to make it accessible via the views APIs.

My understanding is that I create an unmanaged model to handle this. I understand as part of the docs that you need to specify `managed = False` but that's just a start. So far, I've literally only found one link (that isn't very helpful): https://riptutorial.com/django/example/4020/a-basic-unmanaged-table-

Let's say hypothetically, I've got user information that is inputted in many different tables in my existing database and I'd like to create certain data points within my new and unmanaged model to combine it into one serialiser. As of now, this is what I've come up with. Note that in my user model, I don't know what to specify for my `db_tables` parameter since, like I mentioned, data will be coming from many different tables, not just one.

**UserModel**

```
from django.db import models

class UserModel(models.model):
    user = models.CharField(db_column="LABEL", max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "Sample_Table_1"
```

**UserSerializer**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models.user import UserModel

class UserSerializer(serializer.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = "__all__"
```

**UserViewSet**

```
from rest_framewirk.viewsets import ModelViewSet 
from models.user import UserModel 
from serializers.user import UserSerializer

class UserViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def list(self, request **kwargs):
        return super(UserViewSet, self).list(request)
```

Where do I go from here if I wanted to get another data point from a different table other than `db_table = "Sample_Table_1"`? For example, if I wanted data from a `Sample_Table_2` table?

I think my main issue is that I don't really know how unmanaged models work and how I can retrieve data from different tables that already exist in my database. If anyone can point me to a tutorial that can help me with that, it would be a good start.

Comment: You have tables already existing in your database? Refer this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Comment: Yep, I already have tables existing in my database. One, for example, is a user table with a bunch of information of current users.

Comment: your UserModel seems to be named UserDetails...?

Comment: Sorry, that was a copy/paste error. I've changed some of the names because I can't mention the real names I'm working with.

Comment: @Adam, Just to clarify, were the table created by the django migrations that you have performed (eg: You created the models in the `models.py` file and performed migrations) or are you migrating an old project with an existing database?

Comment: @RanjanMP these tables were created with django migrations. So we created the models, and executed `makemigrations` and `migrate` as per the standard way (so we've got the autogenerated migrations py files). What I'm trying to achieve now is following those steps

Comment: @Adam, looks like you just need regular serializers, not model serializers, because the only thing you are getting from these `managed=False` models is listing the fields you'd like to serialize, isn't it?
Define serializers, use SerializerMethodFields where things get tricky and you won't need to touch models at all.

Comment: @NikitaAlmakov you're absolutely right. I don't need to create any additional models and will just need to make a query from my endpoint, using additional serializers depending on the data I need.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to combine data from different tables, you can try with a DB view.
and put an unmanaged model in front of it.
for example:

###### 1) Create a model with managed=False

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
    user = models.CharField(db_column="user", max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = "sample_table_1"
```

###### 2) run makemigrations

Inside the migration file create a DB view (assuming Postgres) with a RunSQL

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('accounts', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='UserModel',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.BigAutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('user', models.CharField(db_column='user', max_length=255)),
            ],
            options={
                'db_table': 'sample_table_1',
                'managed': False,
            },
        ),
        migrations.RunSQL(
            sql="""
                CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW sample_table_1 AS
                SELECT id, username AS user FROM auth_user;
                # Here I used <username> as an example
                """,
            reverse_sql="""
                DROP VIEW IF EXISTS sample_table_1;
                """
        )
    ]
```

###### 3) run migrate

###### 4) create the serializer

```
class UserModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

useful links:
https://www.fusionbox.com/blog/detail/using-materialized-views-to-implement-efficient-reports-in-django/643/

https://schinckel.net/2020/03/03/postgres-view-from-django-queryset/

Answer (score 1):

If one already has tables in the database one should generally use the [`inspectdb` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#inspectdb) management command to generate atleast the basic structure of these tables as models, you might need to fix some things that Django is not able to infer properly. You would (after configuring the database settings properly) run the following command, which will atleast get you started on making the correct models:

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

In general you should refer to the [Integrating Django with a legacy database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/legacy-databases/) section of the documentation.

Moving further, you seem to haven't set the proper table name for your model (since it exists already, it's name might be different from what Django will generate), so if you want a manual fix, you would set the [`db_table` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#db-table) attribute in the model's `Meta`:

```
class UserDetails(models.model):
    user = models.CharField(db_column="LABEL", max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = '<YOUR_TABLE_NAME_HERE>'
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I haven't yet looked at the docs you've mentioned, but what would be the `db_table` name in this case? As I mentioned, this is only an example of one field that I'll be retrieving, but in essence, I'll be combining data from multiple tables.

Comment: `db_table` would be the name of your table in the database, (as my placeholder implies). Suppose in the database the table was named as `users` then you would write `db_table = 'users'`, or similar. Although I would advice using `inspectdb` (you can pass the table names to it to infer specific tables only if needed, check the documentation)

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm misunderstanding something. While this 'user' field in the UserDetails unmanaged model may be getting the data from a `users` table, the model itself will be aggregating data from other tables as well. Does that mean I need to add all the different tables as well?

Comment: @Adam I don't understand what you mean by "the model itself will be aggregating data from other tables". But if you want to use those tables in your application you should make models for them.

Comment: I mean the unmanaged model. I understand the whole point of creating an unmanaged model is so that I wouldn't have to create a new database table when I want to retrieve data from multiple different tables and then serialize that data (using the unmanaged model). Does that make more sense?

Comment: @Adam A model with `managed = False` means that the Django migration system won't manage it (Hence it is generally used for pre-existing / legacy databases). As for what you speak perhaps you talk about the (rarely) used trick that people make by making a model for a _database view_ (If your database is PostgreSQL or Oracle you can use the `--include-views` flag with `inspectdb` and it would generate a model for the view too). If you want to do this manually you would need to declare the fields in the model.

Comment: Sorry, maybe my understanding is not right (which is why it would be very useful to see an example of this). My whole requirement is being able to get data from different existing tables. My assumption was to use a non-managed model so that (as you put it) Django does not manage it. I'm still confused on how I can go about this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232656/discussion-between-adam-and-abdul-aziz-barkat).

Comment: @Adam I don't think Abdul understands you are trying to aggregate fields from multiple remote tables in one Django model. I think this is probably because that's probably impossible. My understanding of models is there is one model to one table. I believe you may be able to omit fields but not add fields to your unmanaged model. I think you need to look somewhere else to aggregate your fields, perhaps by creating a new view in the original database and then creating an unmanaged model to mirror that view. Your database view then does the aggregation.

Comment: @NeilG you aptly explained OP's problem :). I understood that but it seemed OP and I were not able to get our points across to each other. Anyway the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67715762/14991864) by [Aprimus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6091847/aprimus) explains that technique and gives a good example for it.

Comment: Yes, that's right @AbdulAzizBarkat. I just find that foundational principles are rarely stated, though they are highly enlightening and fundamental to understanding; like "one model to one table" or "unmanaged models may omit fields but not add them". It's the biggest difficulty for beginners when foundational knowledge is assumed and not described. Learners have to labour to maintaining permutations of their mental model, when if the foundation was simply stated the mental model would be immediately clarified. Even a good answer and example can be made much easier by stating first principles.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to return data from different model to a single api call one way to achieve this is to user serializers.Serializer

```
class TestClass(serializers.Serializer):
    table1 = serializers.IntegerField()
    ......
```

and you can use this class for serialization.